# MS Access Joins to create a new field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, join

I have three tables in Microsoft Access.

I have a query that joins the first two on an attribute, but need to use the third table to create a "Flag" field if the MeasurementType for a given Name in Table2 is "Allowed".

Eg.

```
Measures            Names                     AllowedTypes
-------             -------                   -------
UniqueVal ------->  UniqueVal (PK)  /------>  Name
Measurement         Name -----------    --->  AllowedType
MeasurementType -----------------------/      ID (PK)
```

My "Merge" query says

```
SELECT Measures.UniqueVal, Measures.Measurement, Measures.MeasurementType, Names,Name
FROM Measures JOIN Names on Measures.UniqueVal = Names.UniqueVal
```

But I need to add a "Flag Field" if the MeasurementType for that Name isn't in the AllowedTypes (There may be more than one allowed type per name).  I tried doing  a join like the one depicted above but I get "Join not allowed" and other such nonsense.  I just can't think my way out of this cardboard box.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access' database engine requires you tell it explicitly what type of JOIN you want: INNER JOIN; LEFT JOIN; RIGHT JOIN.

You also had a misplaced comma in your field list.

My guess is this query is closer to what you want:

```
SELECT Measures.UniqueVal, Measures.Measurement, Measures.MeasurementType, Names.[Name]
FROM Measures INNER JOIN Names on Measures.UniqueVal = Names.UniqueVal
```

Comment: Aaaannnd. The ACE join processor is *stupid* (NB: this is descriptive, *not* general Access-bashing). Checking Help on "Join Expression Not Supported" says that the join's "results may vary depending on the order in which the joins are evaluated." Um, isn't that what parens are supposed to do, enforce evaluation order? Never mind....

Comment: I think what the help file is suggesting is that if you alter the parens, you can change the order of evaluation, and thus the results can be different. Looks like Access/Jet/ACE bashing to me -- you seem to mistake lack of clarity in the help file for a "flaw" in the query optimizer, and instead of assuming inadequate documenation, you blame the query optimizer.